# Slim retorno na mesma página de um envio POST

Tags: php, post, get, slim, delete

Estou enviando uma requisição *post* para uma URL, porém preciso retornar para a mesma página uma mensagem ou alerta dizendo se o ID já está cadastrado ou não.
Já tenho a *query* e método para fazer isso, porém não estou conseguindo mandar o retorno para a mesma pagina.

Metodo de envio :

```
$("sendFormCadastroprod").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/projetoecomerce/admin/cadastroprod",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });


    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log("Dados enviados");
    });


    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        console.error(
            "Error ao enviar: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    request.always(function () {

        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Metodo de recebimento Slim:

```
$app->post('/admin/cadastroprod',function () use ($app) {       
    $sql = new Sql();

    $results = $sql->select("SELECT idproduct FROM tb_products WHERE idproduct = :idproduct",array(

            ":idproduct"=>$_POST["idproduct"]
    ));

    if(empty($results)){
        $products = new Products();

        $products -> insert(    $_POST["idproduct"],
                $_POST["desproduct"],
                $_POST["vlprice"],
                $_POST["vlwidth"],
                $_POST["vlheight"],
                $_POST["vllength"],
                $_POST["vlweigth"],
                $_POST["desurl"]); 
    }else{

        $app->get('/admin/cadastroprod-existente',function () {

        $retorno = array();

        array_push($retorno, array(

                "retorno"=>"code-invalid:already-exists.",
        ));

        return json_encode($retorno);           
        });

    }
    $resposta = "erro";

    header("Location: http://localhost/projetoecomerce/admin/cadastroprod");

    exit;
});
```

Comment: Ué, você está mandando a requisição por ajax não precisa redirecionar. Só dar um echo no json, mas antes precisa colocar o cabeçalho ``header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`` (atenção pro charset, aliás, que pode ser outro)

Comment: Daniel eu estou enviando ao Slim por ajax, porém quanto caio no metodo do slim não consigo obter a resposta, quero que venha alguma resposta dizendo que o usuário já existe porém quanto cai no else ele fica com a tela branca, não redireciona pra lugar nenhum

Comment: troca ``return json_encode($retorno);`` por ``echo json_encode($retorno);``. Vê se resolve

Comment: Então eu consigo obter esse retorno, porém se eu coloco o echo json meu header para redirecionar não funciona, preciso de algo que responda o POST para a mesma pagina entende ? precisava de um retorno do envio do post dizendo que o código já está cadastrado.

Comment: Mas você não pode só retornar um JSON dizendo que já está cadastrado? Você já fez a verificação e tal... Você pode usar um include, ou um método de uma classe pra não ter duplicidade de código. Aliás, bom lembrar que a função ``header()`` sempre precisa vir antes de você dar echo qualquer coisa, pois ele mexe justamente no cabeçalho da requisição.

Comment: Aliás, um cabeçalho de redirecionamento justamente é tratado do lado do navegador, você teria que pegar os cabeçalhos da resposta e fazer um novo Ajax com base no redirecionamento, o que é contra producente do meu ponto de vista.

Comment: na verdade sim eu queria retornar esse JSON dizendo que já está cadastrado, o problema é Como fazer isso redirecionando para a mesma pagina ? e pegar com o ajax para enviar ao formulário ?

Comment: Se você manda por Ajax, ele não recarrega a página, só retorna lá pro javascript o que você mandar do servidor. Se você quer mandar uma nova requisição com base na anterior, pode ler os cabeçalhos da resposta, aí você precisa ler o objeto jqXHR, segue documentação do ``$.ajax()``, procure pela propriedade ``success``: http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax

Comment: eu consegui pegar o retorno, Valeu ele retorna na variavel data, e la eu trato o JSON